# How to run a process/binary on System startup/reboot in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: 20.04, startup, lts, process

I have an Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS, and a binary file to run a process inside folder /home/dir1/dir2 called binary.

1. I believe there might be more than one methods to this but, if I could possibly know please, where and how is (are) the best way(s) to config so this binary/process so it can run automatically upon every time the system restarts?
2. Is there any way to ensure to keep this process/binary keeps running at all time? Meaning, the system keeps checking/monitoring this process, and if it gets killed or stopped manually, or by user or system error etc, it is restarted/re-run automatically?

Any suggestions with config examples would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Systemd can to this for you.

Here is an example of a typical unit file:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/yourdaemon.service
[Unit]
Description=Your Daemon
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target systemd-networkd-wait-online.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/daemon

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And here is a unit file that has restart on failure enabled:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/yourdaemon.service
[Unit]
Description=Your Daemon
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target systemd-networkd-wait-online.service

StartLimitIntervalSec=500
StartLimitBurst=5

[Service]
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s

ExecStart=/path/to/daemon

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I think it's beyond the scope of this answer to go through everything in detail, but in short:

1. Create a unit file for the service (binary/process) you want to start.
2. Make sure to include the `StartLimit` and `Restart` options as indicated above.

[Reference](https://ma.ttias.be/auto-restart-crashed-service-systemd/).

Comment: Thanks mate, the 2nd unit did both for me. You're a gem. Cheers

Comment: For me, in EC2 AL2 instance - I had to enable the service via `systemctl`. `sudo systemctl enable yourdaemon`. You could check if it's enabled by `sudo systemctl is-enabled yourdaemon`