# How to keep webhook listening in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: vps, github

I am setting up a webhook in a VPS so it gets pulls the code from a git repository every time there is a new commit. I have managed to set it up but it only works while `-hooks` is running.

After creating the webhook I use the following command to start listening (Replacing 0.0.0.0 with the actual public IP address of the VPS):

```
/usr/bin/webhook -hooks /root/webhooks/hooks.json -ip "0.0.0.0" -verbose
```

Then I get the following output:

```
[webhook] 2022/12/28 07:47:03 version 2.5.0 starting
[webhook] 2022/12/28 07:47:03 setting up os signal watcher
[webhook] 2022/12/28 07:47:03 attempting to load hooks from /root/webhooks/hooks.json
[webhook] 2022/12/28 07:47:03 found 1 hook(s) in file
[webhook] 2022/12/28 07:47:03   loaded: my-site.com
[webhook] 2022/12/28 07:47:03 serving hooks on http://0.0.0.0:9000/hooks/{id}
[webhook] 2022/12/28 07:47:03 os signal watcher ready
```

And I have configured the webhook in `GitHub`:

```
http://0.0.0.0:9000/hooks/my-site.com
```

The webhook works properly as long as `[webhook] 2022/12/28 07:47:03 os signal watcher ready` is on the screen, but if I press `Ctrl + C` then it is interrupted and the webhook is no longer listening.

Is there a way to keep the webhook listening in the background, so that any time there is a new commit on `GitHub` the VPS gets the latest code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a process/binary on System startup/reboot in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1365334/how-to-run-a-process-binary-on-system-startup-reboot-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts)

Answer (score 0):

After trying and researching a lot I found a way by installing Supervisor to keep the Webhook Server running. The original article is [here](https://willbrowning.me/setting-up-automatic-deployment-and-builds-using-webhooks/).

An extract of the steps mentioned in the article:

1. Install supervisor:

```
sudo apt install supervisor
```

2. Navigate to the `conf.d` folder

```
cd /etc/supervisor/conf.d
```

3. Create a configuration file:

```
sudo nano webhooks.conf
```

4. Add the following inside the configuration file, replacing the username, IP, paths, etc. with your values.

**Note:** The path to your webhook folder can be found with `whereis webhook`.

```
[program:webhooks]
command=bash -c "<path to your webhook folder> -hooks <path to your hooks JSON file>/hooks.json -ip '0.0.0.0' -port '0000' -verbose"
redirect_stderr=true
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=<user>
numprocs=1
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s
stdout_logfile=<path to your hooks JSON file>/supervisor.log
environment=<ENVIRONMENT>="<your/environment>",USER="<user>"
```

5. Save and close the configuration file
6. Execute the following commands

```
touch <path to your hooks JSON file>/supervisor.log
sudo supervisorctl reread
sudo supervisorctl update
sudo supervisorctl start webhooks:*
```

After this, the supervisor will keep your webhook server running.

Comment: You don't need to install anything additional for this. Systemd is installed by default and is meant for managing services.

Comment: Thanks, after 4-5 hours of struggling with it the only way I found was using `supervisor` based on the article I mentioned. To be honest I think I won't try to change it now that is working haha. Have a good day!